# Do not change current directory

Tags: working-directory

I want to have fixed current directory equals to the directory where vim was opened.

Note I am using tabs and splits, so I want to have the same current directory in all tabs and splits. How can I do that?

Comment: The "autochdir" setting, if on, will cause vim to change the working directory "for you." This setting is off by default. If you are seeing vim change the directory thusly, you might try to see if something in your vimrc or some plugin has set autochdir without your knowing.

Answer (score 1):

To change the current directory with the file opened at start up you can add this to your vimrc:

```
 cd %:h
```

By default vim doesn't change the current directory when opening other files so your tabs and splits should not change.

Note that you might be interested by [`:h current-directory`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#current%2Ddirectory)